# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.google.android.apps.common.inject.InjectedApplication

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm trying t use Robolectric

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(
        manifest = "...mypath.../AndroidManifest.xml",
        qualifiers = "fr-normal-port-hdpi",
        sdk = 21,
        application = Application.class)
public class SetPaymentActivityTest {


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void sendWrongPaymentDetails() throws Exception {

        SetPaymentActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(SetPaymentActivity.class)
//                .attach()
                .create()
//                .starst()
//                .resume()
//                .visible()
                .get();
         activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(SetPaymentActivity.class);

//        Shadows.shadowOf(SetPaymentActivity.class);

        String url = activity.getUrl();
        assertThat(url, equalTo(""));
    }
}
```

PROD code:

`public class SetPaymentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements DaggerActivity {`

but I get this error:

```
Time: 109.712
There was 1 failure:
1) sendWrongPaymentDetails(com.google.android.apps.ridematch.payments.SetPaymentActivityTest)
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.google.android.apps.common.inject.InjectedApplication
    at com.google.android.apps.common.inject.ActivityInjectHelper.initGraph(ActivityInjectHelper.java:56)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need your `SetPaymentActivityTest`to extends `InjectedApplication`

like this:

```
public class SetPaymentActivityTest extends InjectedApplication {
```

Comment: why, I never saw it in any example

Comment: This is only an hypothesis. Or maybe the SetPaymentActivity need to be extended. Try if it's helping.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to fix.

Change your test code to next:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(
        constants = BuildConfig.class,
        qualifiers = "fr-normal-port-hdpi",
        sdk = 21)
```

The problem is that `Robolectric` trying to use `Application` as you specified in config and at some point you casting it to your class

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dummy TestApplication class:

`public TestApplication extends InjectedApplication`

and configured:

```
@Config(
        manifest = "...mypath.../AndroidManifest.xml",
        qualifiers = "fr-normal-port-hdpi",
        sdk = 21,
        application = TestApplication.class)
```